# python program error: ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, numpy

I am using python burst_detection package link(https://github.com/nmarinsek/burst_detection/blob/master/README.rst) to try the result. But the program always has some error: ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
The interesting thing is when I remove the value which is larger than 94 in r array, everything works.  It stops at 84th elements because r[83]=342 >94.

The details of the error is like this:

```
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\burst_detection\__init__.py:29: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  return -np.log(np.float(c.binomial(d,r)) * (p**r) * (1-p)**(d-r))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "burstConstructDataPrepare.py", line 33, in <module>
    q, d, r, p = bd.burst_detection(r,d,n,s=2,gamma=1,smooth_win=1)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\burst_detection\__init__.py", line 82, in burst_detection
    q[t] = np.where(cost[t,:] == min(cost[t,:]))
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

The source code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import burst_detection as bd
import numpy as np
r = np.array([5, 8, 12, 12, 2, 4, 11, 15, 2, 3, 4, 29, 30, 10, 7, 1, 24, 18, 2, 2, 2, 2, 54, 2, 8, 2, 3, 12, 4, 2, 6, 18, 4, 4, 12, 2, 8, 2, 3, 2, 2, 5, 2, 2, 3, 9, 7, 8, 6, 9, 6, 1, 4, 20, 2, 16, 19, 2, 11, 4, 2, 38, 6, 7, 1, 2, 14, 4, 8, 2, 4, 2, 2, 6, 8, 27, 4, 2, 14, 2, 14, 8, 4, 2, 342, 4, 2, 2, 14, 14, 6, 2, 2, 6, 2, 4, 2, 1, 5, 10, 27, 6, 2, 2, 2, 14, 12, 16, 2, 48, 16, 6, 3, 2, 4, 2, 2, 1, 320, 4, 4, 8, 6, 238, 12, 6, 4, 10, 6, 2, 10, 4, 19, 10, 3, 1, 2, 32, 8, 4, 6, 2, 4, 2, 18, 10, 18, 4, 4, 4, 6, 2, 13, 2, 4, 47, 2, 2, 4, 10, 5, 4, 2, 12, 34, 4, 6, 8, 8, 8, 20, 2, 1, 4, 6, 2, 8, 29, 4, 14, 6, 8, 2, 28, 4, 18, 2, 2, 2, 7, 4, 2, 2, 8, 2, 6, 8, 1, 2, 6, 4, 1, 246, 6, 43, 14, 16, 2, 7, 4, 4, 12, 8, 8, 2, 14, 4, 19, 4, 2, 8, 16, 8, 14, 3, 12, 3, 4, 3, 4, 6, 2, 16, 5, 2, 3, 2, 11, 301, 10, 2, 2, 8, 1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 8, 2, 2, 4, 2, 8, 4, 6, 2, 34, 14, 25, 11, 2, 5, 34, 2, 1, 2, 2, 6, 2, 1, 6, 4, 4, 2, 5, 2, 2, 1, 25, 1, 21, 10, 14, 10, 4, 4, 6, 4, 4, 4, 28, 36, 2, 7, 2, 1, 5, 5, 2, 8, 23, 2, 104, 4, 2, 81, 5, 10, 4, 2, 20, 4, 4, 12, 4, 4, 7, 2, 2, 6, 1, 2, 4, 2, 16, 4, 2, 2, 32, 26, 2, 3, 5, 8, 34, 11, 2, 15, 4803, 6, 4, 2, 7, 2, 6, 54, 15, 5, 2, 10, 8, 6, 10, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 10, 6, 4, 7, 10, 12, 2, 2, 4, 10, 18, 2, 2, 4, 6, 4, 2, 10, 4, 2, 3, 4, 7, 5, 5, 10, 2, 24, 14, 2, 2, 14, 2, 4, 2, 5, 4, 4, 20, 2, 6, 8, 2, 4, 2, 14, 6, 2, 5, 2, 56, 4, 4, 4, 1, 4, 15, 22, 7, 4, 4, 6, 4, 12, 6, 2, 1, 8, 8, 6, 8, 4, 2, 2, 4, 16, 4, 16, 4, 11, 4, 16, 2, 4, 18, 10, 6, 4, 10, 5, 4, 4, 2, 1, 2, 6, 7, 2, 1, 12, 15, 6, 8, 3, 10, 6, 6, 15, 2, 2, 22, 2, 2, 4, 14, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 7, 2, 3, 4, 20, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 2, 2, 2, 40, 5, 57, 16, 9, 39, 23, 14, 4, 2, 4, 4, 1, 3, 2, 14, 18, 14, 4, 2, 4, 5], dtype=float)
d = np.array([85204, 52148, 51493, 49650, 71615, 40589, 64427, 82750, 106819, 74787, 85377, 103583, 105085, 182878, 62091, 57892, 50195, 93694, 109417, 73217, 55927, 72714, 63947, 55296, 90402, 88750, 65165, 45275, 96197, 25340, 21605, 35532, 47485, 26538, 24425, 23869, 26354, 22754, 21407, 55827, 21632, 22906, 28906, 24859, 21307, 30817, 17375, 9858, 18313, 232498, 19294, 97136, 51202, 37572, 54557, 70766, 57097, 114500, 56602, 45331, 40991, 39157, 38712, 55311, 31137, 97381, 34769, 27199, 26256, 54649, 55692, 20187, 29983, 38937, 18890, 27164, 40477, 26669, 17575, 29507, 24172, 32419, 20765, 22351, 47418, 32246, 30448, 19956, 12941, 14893, 13225, 35730, 19355, 25819, 54119, 110946, 65895, 87889, 39733, 83585, 64361, 59842, 38631, 58091, 48131, 103965, 93565, 79384, 45332, 95638, 95917, 36616, 48542, 33289, 41184, 24751, 30682, 43297, 24261, 32458, 30735, 25613, 26687, 44623, 21578, 26780, 27357, 24233, 43731, 65909, 39591, 46440, 34500, 63942, 37372, 110805, 100447, 36929, 90949, 82508, 50365, 60669, 85053, 99502, 31699, 43013, 33139, 20893, 25020, 21772, 19161, 19574, 25259, 21669, 29567, 25830, 28928, 39378, 18625, 35365, 20150, 28809, 20157, 12458, 18612, 18951, 36695, 30367, 27935, 17827, 38211, 47211, 32846, 50263, 33010, 64535, 38932, 64244, 47936, 65004, 93956, 121679, 135349, 92521, 57248, 60545, 96179, 61296, 82527, 129102, 57743, 27099, 27526, 77945, 47691, 72254, 30493, 31201, 30027, 18517, 51830, 45119, 34492, 19145, 28046, 39817, 32189, 26649, 22680, 35697, 20009, 27063, 22006, 17429, 21850, 36964, 22783, 29280, 17551, 16710, 21856, 56571, 29912, 78352, 47126, 119015, 58523, 53470, 117603, 113078, 90366, 152835, 84910, 44449, 48737, 90380, 36751, 21517, 61106, 43713, 31013, 32848, 35680, 34321, 28032, 28998, 21993, 17442, 25893, 35886, 18890, 21404, 21068, 31837, 24098, 22238, 22874, 79276, 59551, 56030, 51519, 56161, 69342, 44812, 75656, 147183, 101918, 117934, 101308, 48944, 72581, 83213, 39094, 45053, 41858, 93766, 24785, 44300, 32312, 44351, 46431, 22052, 22717, 30312, 17618, 18482, 32053, 30781, 23381, 25085, 38552, 17232, 7446, 31514, 31803, 52601, 59064, 57327, 83281, 52313, 102054, 81384, 46131, 41147, 92202, 83376, 71833, 81751, 50042, 139309, 88766, 65899, 73897, 13498, 24365, 54974, 55356, 55169, 70458, 34189, 22680, 30344, 29500, 29508, 20756, 23004, 28998, 19748, 24246, 45116, 19455, 45974, 34776, 28558, 52504, 100644, 36647, 34962, 62670, 86643, 72854, 149450, 144966, 64755, 160236, 107847, 169807, 45338, 118870, 59907, 54753, 95093, 53541, 40316, 41518, 30616, 62899, 24178, 32149, 31800, 16248, 26890, 23822, 24347, 21534, 32738, 34430, 26452, 22751, 24797, 32184, 21959, 14426, 21093, 22693, 35388, 38083, 20472, 96580, 48828, 41702, 80508, 59900, 69009, 150823, 50156, 124057, 79322, 99327, 37164, 48447, 73061, 23266, 60930, 32194, 27431, 48665, 23644, 23114, 19836, 20855, 26099, 18557, 34715, 69252, 35369, 24415, 27723, 75882, 80116, 93982, 93600, 48240, 30530, 70467, 48381, 68071, 111650, 49644, 48321, 67175, 36795, 38703, 45768, 25008, 101486, 118644, 28467, 27976, 40437, 35654, 36718, 37723, 27918, 21014, 39288, 36771, 35745, 59531, 15936, 18691, 13160, 22037, 20341, 26777, 33097, 21118, 10619, 51840, 37167, 37119, 17560, 95647, 49868, 102463, 43691, 58891, 117927, 59001, 55306, 60960, 62106, 37680, 71267, 69463, 103003, 39256, 57695, 36497, 32099, 42077, 29675, 39168, 22153, 65598, 45505, 27221, 24101, 35195, 25168, 21496, 20437, 27609, 22490, 31317, 23305, 20425, 14547, 32549, 37037, 19987, 49525, 81588, 74676, 88173, 63231, 124179, 88269, 66430, 48514, 63505, 52358, 45551, 32175, 16347, 47466, 49138, 32070, 19425, 39898, 25584, 29265, 28505, 36205], dtype=float)
n = len(r)

q, d, r, p = bd.burst_detection(r,d,n,s=2,gamma=1,smooth_win=1)
bursts = bd.enumerate_bursts(q, 'burstLabel')
weighted_bursts = bd.burst_weights(bursts,r,d,p)

print('observed probabilities: ')
print(str(r/d))

print('optimal state sequence: ')
print(str(q.T))

print('baseline probability: ' + str(p[0]))

print('bursty probability: ' + str(p[1]))

print('weighted bursts:')
print(weighted_bursts)
```

Then I tried only put 10 or 20 elements to r and d, it works. When it has 524 elements, it shows this kind of error. 
Does someone know why?
Thanks!

Comment: Check your numpy version. Of course this can be a bug and the warning is scary too, but maybe the author used a newer version of numpy. I also don't think the size of your input is the reason, but more the hidden effects by *other data*.

Comment: Add a `pdb.set_trace()` and (then) a breakpoint on the `burst_detection` line that fails and see what the typical values look like.  Then run until it crashes (with `pdb.pm()`) and see what the broken value looks like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like is a bug in the `burst_detection` package. I don't know what that line is supposed to do, but the line

```
q[t] = np.where(cost[t,:] == min(cost[t,:]))
```

will try to set the left side, `q[t]`, which is a single array element, to the right hand side. This works fine when only one of the costs is equal to the minimum cost, but when two of the states share the same minimum cost, the right hand side will have length 2. To have it just pick one of those optimal states, you want to change that line to

```
q[t] = np.where(cost[t,:] == min(cost[t,:]))[0]
```

You can do that by going to wherever the package was installed and editing that line manually. If you think the package maintainer would fix this, you could also open an issue on their tracker on GitHub.

Comment: File "burstConstructDataPrepare.py", line 84, in burst_detection
    q[t] = np.where(cost[t,:] == min(cost[t,:]))[0]
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (0) into shape (1)

Comment: The reason that's happening is that at that time, `cost[t, :]` is filled with NaNs. This is getting to be in-depth enough that the package maintainer, who knows this code better than you or I do, should be working on this bug.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you find any solution for this ?